# How to dynamically create multiple threads with multiple corresponding classes for solving many sudoku puzzles

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

My task is to write a multi threaded program that solves a set of sudoku puzzles by dynamically determining the maximum number of threads that can run on the machine, then allocate that many threads to grab single puzzles from the file with all the sudoku puzzles.

Something like: we have determined that 8 threads can run on this machine, so we'll allocate 8 threads. Then these 8 threads take turns grabbing individual sudoku puzzles from the pile and solving them, and writing them to a new file with the solutions

What I currently have so far is a fully working code to grab the first puzzle, solve, and write it to the solution file. But I need to make it multi threaded and have it do this for all the rest of the puzzles too. I have a class that holds the sudoku puzzle data called SudokuGrid, which has the 9x9 array.

**I'm struggling with the concept of allocating the threads and allocating a class for each thread, I think I can generate an array to hold the threads but how do I allocate corresponding class instances?** I believe I'll need one instance for each thread since they'll be working on their own different puzzles. I'm supposed to use std::thread for this.

Comment: why to allocate the classes?! Since u have a code do the work. I suppose it takes the path for the puzzle file and then creates a new solution file with a unique name. i.e. a void taking a single argument like `std::string const &`

Comment: my single threaded code uses the class already, i may not have specified but we're required to use a class to hold the sudoku grid data

My code takes the path for the puzzle file and then solves the first one and writes the solution to a new file

Comment: You would be allocating `object`s of `class`es, not allocating `class`es. To make a new thread (using `std::thread` ) you need to call a function/method. So I guess in your case you could make an array of your objects, and in a loop or something you could call a method of the each of the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your question directly (ie. not helping you with the logic of solving the puzzle, but just helping you with allocating and managing threads to methods), this is a minimalistic example of how to set up objects to do some work on different threads:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <thread>

struct Foo
{
    int count;

    void Bar (int n)
    {
        count = 0;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            count += std::rand() % n;
    }
};

void SetUpMultiThreading (std::vector<Foo> & foo)
{
    int n = foo.size();

    std::vector<std::thread> threads(n); 
    
    // the below (2*i+5) is just some mock data input

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        threads[i] = std::thread(&Foo::Bar, std::ref(foo[i]), 2*i+5); 
        
    // Note that without std::ref (or a custom wrapper instead)
    // then the foo element would be copied to the std::thread
    // function, so you'd lose access to the results

    for (auto & t : threads)
        t.join();
}

void CheckWork (const std::vector<Foo> & foo)
{
    for (auto & f : foo)
        std::cout << f.count << std::endl;
}

int main ()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    const int n = 8;
    
    std::vector<Foo> foo(n);
    SetUpMultiThreading(foo);
    CheckWork(foo);
}
```

Comment: I think this solves most of my confusion for now, except I am still unsure about the class thing. Let's say I want to create a SudokuGrid class instance for each thread to work with, how do I do that with a unique name for each so that I don't cause conflict between the threads?

Comment: @XH192, I'm not sure that I understand you. *Object* instances of a class *are* unique. And so long as there's no static data then they each have their own data. As for the name, each object *does* have a "name": `foo[i]` and `foo[i+1]`, etc. The above code demonstrates this: each `foo` element has a *different* value for its data (in this case `count`).

Comment: Oh okay, I think I get it now. So the classes don't actually need an actual name, they can be referenced purely through the array. That was what I was unsure about, how to reference them, but I get it now thank you Elliott!

Comment: @XH192, You're welcome. But there's one thing that you must understand: the difference between a `class` and an object of a `class`. You seem to use the word `class` when you mean to use the word object. I'd recommend googling these two terms to get a clearer definition.

Comment: You're right, I think I had the terminology a bit mixed up. The class is the template, and the object is the template once it's filled in? But I use the word class instance/instantiated class instead of "object of class", is this also acceptable?

Comment: @XH192, yep, I think' that's a good summary. "class instance" is the same as "object" but don't abbreviate it to "class"; if you want it shorter then just use "object".

Comment: Everything was good except I couldn't replicate this loop in your example:
 for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        threads[i] = std::thread(&Foo::Bar, std::ref(foo[i]), 2*i+5); 

I tried to do it like so:
threads[i] = std::thread(&SudokuGrid::solveSudoku(), std::ref(sudokuGrids[i]));

but it complained that I'm calling a non static member function without an object argument, so then I tried threads[i] = std::thread(&sudokuGrids[i]::solveSudoku(), std::ref(sudokuGrids[i])); which is closer to how i was doing it single threaded, but that doesn't work either

Comment: @XH192, change `&SudokuGrid::solveSudoku()` to `&SudokuGrid::solveSudoku`.  but actually, the first part, `A` of  `&A::B` is the name of the 'class', not of the 'vector' object.

Comment: wow your response was insanely quick, and oops i somehow added that parentheses on my own by reflex

Comment: @XH192, no problem. Also, ignore my second sentence. I had misread.